# Is there a sensible way to compose "algebraic sets" between objects?

Tags: category-theory

> **Definition 0.** Given a category $\mathbf{C}$ with objects $X$ and $Y$, lets define that an *algebraic set* $X \nrightarrow Y$ is a subset $\Phi$ of $\mathbf{C}(X,Y)$ such that there exists an object $I$ together with morphisms $f:I \rightarrow X$ and $g:I \rightarrow Y$ such that $$\forall \varphi : X \rightarrow Y \qquad \varphi \in \Phi \iff \varphi \circ f = g.$$

If I'm not mistaken, algebraic sets $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \nrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the above sense are in canonical bijective correspondence with algebraic subsets of $n$-dimensional affine space in the classical sense. For example, in the category of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, there's an algebraic set $x^2+y^2=1:\mathbb{R}[x,y] \nrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ consisting of all morphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{R}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(x)^2+\varphi(y)^2=1_\mathbb{R}.$ To see that this an algebraic set, let $I=\mathbb{R}[\alpha]$ and define $f(\alpha) = x^2+y^2$ and $g(\alpha)=1,$ then extend $f$ and $g$ to morphisms of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

Now, I don't know anything about algebraic geometry, but I'm interested in using the notion of an "algebraic set" given above to formalize certain concepts in basic linear algebra. The way I see it, a system of linear equations like

\begin{align*} 
\alpha : 2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
\beta : 3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}

"is" a span in $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{Mod}$. Define

- $I = \mathbb{R}\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$
- $X = \mathbb{R}\langle x,y\rangle$
- $Y = \mathbb{R}$
- $f(\alpha) = 2x-5y, f(\beta) = 3x+9y$
- $g(\alpha) = 8, g(\beta) = -12$

Then the above system "is" the span $(I,f,g) : X \nrightarrow Y.$ And, a solution to this system "is" an element of the corresponding algebraic set.

Now recall that two systems of linear equations are *equivalent* iff their solution sets are equal. We can generalize as follows:

> **Definition 1.** Given a category $\mathbf{C}$ with objects $X$ and $Y$, two spans $S,T : X \nrightarrow Y$ are *equivalent* iff the corresponding algebraic sets are equal.

Long story short, I plan to use these notions to get a better grasp on so-called "elementary" linear algebra. But something's bothering me, namely that I can't quite tell whether there's a category here with objects equal to $\mathrm{obj}(\mathbf{C})$ and arrows being algebraic sets:

> **Question.** Is there a sensible way to compose "algebraic sets" between objects, and if so, is it associative?

Comment: Other than it's weak, what's the issue with the usual [composition of spans](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span) via pullback?

Comment: @DerekElkins, I find pullbacks pretty tricky. Maybe it's obvious, but can you offer a proof that this actually works?

Comment: Not sure I understand: do you want those 'algebraic sets' to be the objects of some category, or the (1-)morphisms in some (higher, weak?) category?

Comment: @Ben, is that more clear?

Comment: Dear @goblin, it's clear now. One quick observation without giving it too much thought: if $C$ has all limits, then to any subset $\Phi\subset C(X,Y)$ we can associate the limit of all graphs of all $\varphi\in\Phi$, giving a span $I_\Phi\to X\times Y$. Conversely, with each span $I\to X\times Y$ we can associate the algebraic set $\Phi_I\subset C(X,Y)$ consisting of the $\varphi$ such that the span factors through its graph. This induces some algebraisation (or 'closure') $\Phi\mapsto \Phi_{I_{\Phi}}$. Then the composition should be the closure of the evident composition. Does this work?

Comment: @Ben Yep.  In particular, you only need wide equalizers.  The span is *exactly* the equalizer of all the $\phi$ in the algebraic set.  As you mention, *any* subset of $C(X,Y)$ will induce a span by taking the equalizer of all the elements.  Then this span induces an algebraic set (via an equalizer in **Set** incidentally).  These can be combined to make the "closure" operator that you mention. This still leads to at least two distinct potential notions of composition.  The first is to take the closure of the set of all composites of the algebraic sets (it will not be an algebraic set ...

Comment: ... itself in general).  The second is to take the pullback (which will require binary products in addition to all equalizers) as suggested in my first comment.  Since this operates at the level of spans, it identifies a unique algebraic set.  However, the resulting pullback is not itself (in general) the cone of an equalizer of subsets of $C(X,Y)$ for the appropriate $X$ and $Y$. The algebraic set induced by the pullback span can be perhaps surprising relative to the component algebraic sets.